# git new created file automatically becomes committed

Tags: git

The newly created .xml file auto becomes the submitted status.

I can't use git commit and push.

But I newly created .java file iscorrect state.

It's ma .gitignore,but I think it has nothing to do with it.

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
/.idea/*.xml
```

Help me,Online waiting for.Thx

Comment: Provide more information, so that you don't get down votes

Comment: I understand that there is a language barrier here but you need to rewrite your question so that it becomes clearer. In particular, what does it mean that the file becomes "the submitted status"? Why can't you use git commit and push? Do you get error messages? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,I have modified the /Users/myname/.gitignore_global file.This file I add a line to ignore the *.xml.So,When I create a new XML file, it automatically changes from green to grey.